# Equivalent conditions for a finitely presented module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, proof-explanation, localization

I have a few questions regarding the proof of Corollary 7.21 from [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).

**$(i)\implies (ii)$**:

1. Why $M_\mathfrak p=M_{f_i}\otimes_{R_{f_i}}R_\mathfrak p$?
2. How does the freeness of $M_\mathfrak p$ over $R_\mathfrak p$ follow from that of $M_{f_i}$ over $R_{f_i}$ (and the above)?

**$(ii)\implies (i)$**:

When we localize $u:R^n\rightarrow M$ at $\mathfrak p$, we get $u_\mathfrak p: R_\mathfrak p^n\rightarrow M_\mathfrak p$, a homomorphism of $R_\mathfrak p$-modules.

3. If we apply Proposition 7.20c), shouldn't we get $f_{\mathfrak p}\in R_\mathfrak p\setminus \mathfrak p R_\mathfrak p$ instead of $f_\mathfrak p\in R\setminus \mathfrak p$ (since we have a homomorphism of $R_\mathfrak p$-modules instead of that of $R$-modules)?
4. To apply Proposition 7.20c), we also need to know that $M_\mathfrak p$ is finitely presented over $R_\mathfrak p$. Why is that so?

Comment: For 4: $M$ is finitely presented by hypothesis, so there is an exact sequence of $R$-modules $0 \to K \to F \to M \to 0$ with $F$ free and both $K, F$ finitely generated. Since localization is an exact functor, localizing at $\mathfrak{p}$ gives an exact sequence $0 \to K_{\mathfrak{p}} \to F_{\mathfrak{p}} \to M_{\mathfrak{p}} \to 0$ with $F_{\mathfrak{p}}$ free, and $F_{\mathfrak{p}}, K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ finitely generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1.$ The is because  the multiplicative subset $\{f^k\mid k\in\mathbf N\}$ is contained in the multiplicative subset $S=R\smallsetminus\mathfrak p$, hence
$$M_f\otimes_{R_f}R_\mathfrak{p}=(M\otimes_RR_f)\otimes_{R_f}R_\mathfrak{p}\simeq M\otimes_RR_\mathfrak{p}=M_\mathfrak{p}.$$

$2.$ Extension of scalars preserves freeness (for any $R$ algebra $A$, $R^n\otimes_RA\simeq A^n$).

$3.$ It should, but $f_\mathfrak p$ can be multiplied by a unit in $R_\mathfrak p$, and you just have to multiply by the denominator to get an element in (the canonical image of) $R$.

$4.$ Finite presentation is preserved by extension of scalars since tensor product is a right exact functor.

Comment: Could you please enlarge on question 3 a bit and make your statements more precise? We have an isomorphism $u_p: R_p^n\rightarrow M_p$ of $R_p$-modules, and the proposition tells us that there is $f\in R_p\setminus pR_p$ such that $u_f: R_f^n\rightarrow M_f$ is an isomorphism of $R_f$-modules. We need to find $f_p\in R\setminus p$ such that the same property holds. How do you construct $f_p$ from $f$ and why is the resulting localization map an isomorphism?

Comment: If $f_\mathfrak{p}=\dfrac fs$, $s\in R\smallsetminus \mathfrak p$,  you replace $f_\mathfrak{p}$ with $\dfrac f1$. This is because, in any ring, if $u$ is a unit, $x$ is a unit if and if $ux$ is.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. You start with $f_p=\frac{f}{s}\in R_p\setminus pR_p$, i.e., $f,s\in R\setminus p$ (the existence of which is guaranteed by the proposition). What do you mean by "replacing"? Do these elements equal in some ring? I can't relate the fact about units to this. Moreover, eventually you get an element $\frac{f}{1}$, which is not in $R\setminus p$. I guess one also needs to replace this element with $f$, which is in $R\setminus p$.

Comment: I use the fact that, if $S$ and $T$ are two multiplicative subsets of $R$, we have an isomorphism $S^{-1}\bigl(T^{-1}R\bigr)\simeq (ST)^{-1}R$, and that, if $S=R\smallsetminus\mathfrak p$ and $T=\{f^k\}$, then $ST=S$. Is it clearer?

Comment: No, it isn't. :(

Comment: In fact, I no longer understand what my original question consisted in. We have a homomorphism of $R$-modules $u: R^n\rightarrow M$, and $u_p$ is an isomorphism. Thus by the proposition we get $f_p\in R\setminus p$ immediately. Thank you for your explanations!

Comment: I think you were misled by the notation $f_{\mathfrak p}$ which implicitly suggests that $f_{\mathfrak p}$ lies in $R_{\mathfrak p}$ — which is not the case, as you finally found out.